# Merge object with object in array of objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects that looks something like

```
{  
   "foo":[  
      {  
         "bar":"boo"
      },
      {  
         "baz":"bang"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to update `baz` with a new value but I cannot work out how to merge both these objects?

I tried something like `Object.assign({}, foo,{baz: 'beep'})`

But this did not work?

Comment: Using unique keys in each object in array is a horrible structure to start with. If you control the source  change to single object there

Comment: I don't have control of the source, this is an object from an API I will be updating and sending back as a PATCH

Comment: obj.foo[1].baz = 'lol'; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foo is an Array of objects to replace it with new value, try the following:
```

```js
var obj =  { "foo":[ { "bar":"boo" }, { "baz":"bang" } ] };
var index = obj.foo.findIndex((o) =>Object.keys(o).includes("baz"));
if(index != -1)
  Object.assign(obj.foo[index], {baz: 'beep'});
  
  console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create a modified copy of `foo`, use `Array.prototype.map`:

```js
const foo = [  
  {  
     "bar":"boo"
  },
  {  
     "baz":"bang"
  }
];

const newFoo = foo.map(value => {
  if('baz' in value) return Object.assign({}, value, {a: 'b'});
  return value;
});

console.log(newFoo);
```

Comment: Think OP wants to update  existing not create new object

Comment: Almost yes, I do not want to update the existing one, more create a new, copy of the existing one, with an updated prop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't necessarily know the array index of the element you're trying to modify, you'll need to search through that array to find it -- for example using `Array.find()`:

```js
let quux = {  
   "foo":[  
      {  
         "bar":"boo"
      },
      {  
         "baz":"bang"
      }
   ]
}

quux.foo.find(
  (obj) => {
    return obj.baz === "bang"
  }
).baz="beep";

console.log(quux);
// This mutates the original object; if you need a clone wrap this in an Object.assign as shown in other answers
```

(Arrays of objects can be inconvenient for this reason; you may be better off with an object of objects, so there's an ID for each.)